# Next.js warnings about Images

Tags: image, next.js

I get warnings in the client console for every image that I use like that:

```
       <Image
      src="/login/rightSideMainImage.svg"
      alt="blue_ellipse"
      width={760}
      height={760}
    />
```

> Image with src [x] has either width or height modified, but not the
> other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include
> the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect
> ratio.

so I found a temporary solution to add the sizes again in the style.

```
  <Image
      src="/login/rightSideMainImage.svg"
      alt="blue_ellipse"
      width={760}
      height={760}
      style={{ width: 760, height: 760 }}
    />
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?

It looks bad to write the same parameters twice just to avoid warnings.

Comment: Can you share the css code in `self-end` class?

Comment: @RobinThomas - It's a premade class from tailwind-css library :
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-self

Comment: If you remove that class from `Image`, does your warning go away?

Comment: @RobinThomas no, I updated the question and removed this class so it will not confuse

Comment: How the parent element of `<Image>` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to avoid scaling the SVG and just want it to be fixed in place, the best way to avoid redundancy here would be to simply set the `layout = "fixed"`, which allows you to set a fixed width and height without triggering the warning. You can learn more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/images#image-sizing).

However, if you plan on scaling your SVG, you could either set `layout=”responsive”` and set the max width and height using the `style` parameter like `style={{ maxHeight:"100%", maxHeight:"100%" }}`. Alternatively, you could avoid the entire hassle of coding by simply using a (Content Delivery Network) like Google CDN or Cloudinary to deliver your images. These will help you add additional image transformations that will also provide responsive images for different devices.